# rbenv command not found despite installation

Tags: ruby, linux, rbenv

I would like to use rbenv to control my ruby environment. I followed the basic gethub checkout installation instructions in this site: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#understanding-path

However when i use rbenv command, it says that it isnt found!! When I type

`source ~/.bash_profile`

(where rbenv path is indicated), into the command line, it says 
export: Command not found!!

What a i suppose to do at this point? I need rbenv to install gems because I dont have permission to install (even if i use sudo i need permission). I followed the installation instructions correctly, what is the source of the problem?

info about OS:

```
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release:        6.5
Codename:       Santiago
```

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: @NaimRajib what about now?

Comment: Modify your ``~/.bashrc`` instead of ``~/.bash_profile``

Comment: @NaimRajib I did that but am still facing the same problem.

Comment: When you type `type export` into your shell, what is the response?

Comment: @Jesper it does not recognize the command `type` .

Comment: What shell are you running?

Comment: @Jesper i am using CSH

Answer (score 0):

Most of the instructions for installing `rbenv` are valid for bash and similar POSIX compliant shells. C Shell is not POSIX compliant. This means, among other things, that some commands will not be present or have different names.

So some things to take note of:

- You may want to use a file called `.cshrc` instead of `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.
- The equivalent of `export` in csh is `set` or `setenv`, depending on what kind of behavior you're looking for: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-difference-between-set-and-setenv-c-shell-variable/
- You may need to run rehash after changing ruby versions: http://blog.hplogsdon.com/multiple-ruby-versions-a-battle-between-rbenv-and-rvm-csh-edition/

To minimize confusion, I'd recommend checking if you can change your default shell to something like `bash` or `zsh`.